# Service connection creation operation failed in Azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm new to Azure platform. I'm trying free trial and creating a CI/CD setup for docker by following from the below link.

https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/docker/

[image]

I have no issue until setting up build definition. I'm getting below issues when doing changes in the release definition.

[image]

when i click on "Authorize" button in azure subscription, I'm getting below issue.

Please let me know what mistake i am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new service connection and mapped in the release definition.

1. [Click on Manage link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN1ao.png)
2. [Click on New service connection button
   at top right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIljf.png)
3. [Select Azure resource manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhRAG.png)

Once you select the respective option and click Next. Enter valid name and select respective subscription and resource group details.

Answer (score 1):

well, the text says it all. you are trying to create a connection with a name that already exists. you need to call it something different or rename the existing one

Comment: not sure why do you call it a suggestion, when its a solution :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers